# LVM + how to add to partition space after we increased the VM disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel, lvm

We have VM with a Redhat 7. We get on the partition /data 100%:

```
# df -h | grep data
 /dev/sdc                   20G   20G     0 100% /data
```

So we increase the VM disk to ~30G, and after re-scan, we got:

```
# sfdisk -s | grep sdc
 /dev/sdc:  31457280
```

Now we need to add the free 10G to /data:

Please advice what are the next steps with LVM command to add on  /data the free 10G?

The current configuration is:

```
# pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
 /dev/sda2  vg_lab lvm2 a--  149.51g 94.00m


df -hT /data
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc       ext4   20G   20G     0 100% /data
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `/dev/sdc` is managed with LVM but is rather directly formatted. So you do not need to resize LVMs, just grow the filesystem. It would be helpful if you replace the output of `df -h` with the output of `df -hT /data` and add the output of `parted /dev/sdc print free`.

Comment: see my update FS already created on /dev/sdc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

1. A "physical" disk `/dev/sdc`
2. This `/dev/sdc` doesn't have a partition table, rather it has a whole-disk format.
3. You have also a `/dev/sda`, which *has* a partition table,
4. On this partition table, it has a `/dev/sda2`, which is a physical LVM volume.

You increased `/dev/sdc`, *which wasn't part of the LVM volume group*, and now you want to see the newly extended free space.

---

Interpreting your question literally, the answer is this:

As your `/dev/sdc` wasn't part of your LVM volume group, you don't have to anything with the LVM. You can simply use `resize2fs /dev/sdc`. Either with a mounted partition, using the online ext4 resize feature in your kernel, or you could also offline resize it (typically, from a rescue disk).

---

The answer for your true problem:

it is that you mixed the LVM and the traditional partitional tables. I think you wanted to have a full-LVM system, and you wanted to insert your `/dev/sdc` into your volume group. So you could create/resize/move your logical volumes, and it wouldn't matter on which physical disks are they at the moment.

My own opinion about this, the best if your *whole system* is in the LVM, i.e. you don't have a single partition table. This is incompatible with grub, but it an be made working with lilo (and, in the case of a virtualized system, you can also create a minimal hard disk only for booting, so it will work also with grub).

You didn't do it while you installed your system. My advice would be to convert your `/dev/sdc` into an LVM physical volume. It could be hard now, because it would destroy all data on it, but it can be still done. Although it is already not your question.

---

*Extension:* seeing that your `/dev/sda2` is quite large, you may copy first all data from `/dev/sdc` into it, then reformat the `/dev/sdc` as a physical volume (`pvcreate /dev/sdc`), add it into your volume group (`vgextend vg_lab /dev/sdc`), and then copying everything back (probably into a new logical volume on your newly extended volume group).

Comment: what about lvextend  + resize2fs after vgextend ?

Comment: @yael It depends on, what you want to get. You can do `lvextend` only if you have enough free PEs (physical extents) on your VG. If you don't have, first you have to extend your volume group (probably with the newly re-formatted `/dev/sdc` as a physical volume). But it would destroy all data on it, so first you have to back it up (probably into an already existing logical volume, or into a newly created one, on your vg).